# Column 'Product.product_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server

I have records as above

```html
<table>
<thead>
<th>
Product_name  </th><th>  Product_optioncode </th><th>  Product_id </th><th>  itemprice</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>aaaaaaaa </td><td> 1001</td><td> 101 </td><td> $10</td><tr>
<tr><td>aaaaaaaa </td><td>1001</td><td>102</td><td>$12</td><tr>
<tr><td>bbbbbbbb </td><td>1001</td><td> 103</td><td>$17</td><tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

```
        select              
          prd.product_name,
          prd.product_optioncode,
          prd.Product_id,
          prd.product_link,
          prd.product_image,
          Count(prd.Product_id) as qty,
          Min(prd.itemprice) as minprice,
          Max(prd.itemprice) as maxprice,
          mnf.manufacturer_name as brnd,
          prd.product_enabled,
          prd.product_showhomepage
     from Product prd
     left join manufacturer mnf on prd.manufacturer_id=mnf.manufacturer_id
     Where product_showhomepage = 1
     group by product_optioncode
```

i need query result as

product name : aaaaaaaa   optioncode: 1001   minprice : $10  maxprice : $17 and other columns. How do i make this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either GROUP BY or aggregate all of the columns in your query. If you actually need to group by Product.OptionCode, then you will be grouping multiple products together. When you do that, you can't display each product's name, ID, etc. Your final query should look something like this:

```
select              
--    prd.product_name,
    prd.product_optioncode,
--    prd.Product_id,
--    prd.product_link,
--    prd.product_image,
    Count(prd.Product_id) as qty,
    Min(prd.itemprice) as minprice,
    Max(prd.itemprice) as maxprice  --,
--    mnf.manufacturer_name as brnd,
--    prd.product_enabled,
--    prd.product_showhomepage
from Product prd
left join manufacturer mnf on prd.manufacturer_id=mnf.manufacturer_id
Where product_showhomepage = 1
group by product_optioncode
```

So, your output will only include the OptionCode, the number of products, the min and the max prices.

Comment: If you also need to group by Product Name, then you uncomment that field above and change your GROUP BY to `GROUP BY product_optioncode, product_name`.